# How to uninstall a program that was not installed using the package manager on Linux Mint?

Tags: python, linux-mint, uninstall, apt-get, source-code

So, I installed [Canto](http://codezen.org/canto-ng) Atom/RSS reader using the source from the official website, but it was throwing me errors so I installed it using `apt-get` (this worked).

Now, I want to uninstall the original but I dont know how, as there is no make file so I cannot do `make uninstall`, there's only `setup.py` and it only has options to `build` or `install`. How do I remove it from my system?

I'm running Linux Mint 14 64-bit, btw.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but the solution is something I was looking for at one point in the past for ImageMagick I installed from source  on Ubuntu, so I will share what I learned, from my experience.

The key: Build your own `.deb` package as a part of the install process using [`checkinstall`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall). As the official Ubuntu `checkinstall` page explains:

> CheckInstall keeps track of all files installed by a "make install" or equivalent, creates a Slackware, RPM, or Debian package with those files, and adds it to the installed packages database, allowing for easy package removal or distribution.

So knowing that, let’s install `checkinstall` like this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
```

Note I am adding `build-essential` to the mix to ensure your compiling environment is solid.

Now, run this command to install all of the dependencies—libraries and such—needed by Canto:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep canto
```

Once that is done, download the Canto source code of the *exact version you want to remove* and then build the binary from the source by running `./configure` like this:

```
./configure
```

But instead of the next typical steps of `make` and `sudo make install` run this command instead:

```
sudo checkinstall
```

That will build the `.deb` package and install Canto again. Don’t panic! When that install is done, look at the final output and it should say something like:

```
You can remove it from your system anytime using:

     sudo dpkg -r canto-1.2.3
```

And there you go! You can remove Canto! And this works for most any source code compiled on a Debian setup such as Linux Mint.

If this can’t help the original post 6+ years later, I hope this helps someone else who comes across this!